# Does Glass have default activity?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I've noticed that in the `Manifest` file for the Glass project, we don't have to declare default `Activity`.

Does this mean that Glass does not have a default `Activity`? Then the term default does not exist in Glass since we are allowed to start **ANY `ACTIVITY`** just by using voice commands?